# Is it possible to automatically insert the same image to every third slide

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using custom fields and would like to add an image to every third slide.. How do you do this.. could it possibly be done with jQuery and how?? So new to this

```
    <div class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides slide-ul">
            <?php while(the_repeater_field('text_scroll')): ?>
                <li class="slide">
                    <span class="scroll-text1 slider"><?php the_sub_field('scroll_top_text');?></span>
                     <span class="scroll-text2 slider"><?php the_sub_field('scroll_bottom_text');?></span>
                </li>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [nth child selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f8Skv/)

```
$('.slide:nth-child(3n)').append('<img src="IMage.jpg" />');
```

Answer (score 1):

Using normal PHP

```
<div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides slide-ul">
        <?php $i=0 ; while(the_repeater_field( 'text_scroll')): 
        if($i % 3===0 ){echo '<li>each 3rd row this row will display</li>';} ?>
        <li class="slide"> 
            <span class="scroll-text1 slider">
                <?php the_sub_field('scroll_top_text');?>
            </span>
             <span class="scroll-text2 slider">
                 <?php the_sub_field('scroll_bottom_text');?>
            </span>
        </li>
        <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```